# Why is my thread executing the target function before I start it?

Tags: python, multithreading, python-multithreading

I would like to understand why I must wait for my receiver thread to end its work before I can do anything else.
I understand that my sock_listen function is awaiting a connection, that's what its meant for, but I don't understand why this isn't happening "within" my thread.

Sorry if this is a stupid question but I'm kind of lost ! 
Thank you in advance!

```
def sock_listen(address, port):
    sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    server_address = (address,port)
    print("Starting listener on %s and port %s" % server_address)
    sock.bind(server_address)
    sock.listen(1)
    while True:
        print("[-] Waiting for connection")
        connection, client_address = sock.accept()
        print("[+] Connection from " + str(client_address))
        data = connection.recv(256)
        while (data) :
            print("[" + time.strftime("%H:%M:%S") + "] " + str(data))
            data = connection.recv(256)

receiver = threading.Thread(sock_listen("localhost",10000))
print("Nothing reaches me, I can not be printed until the sock_connect func is done looping!")

receiver.start()
```

My objective is to make a TCP simple chat in which a dedicated thread would handle and print incoming messages and the main process would send the user input (messages)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you write `threading.Thread(sock_listen("localhost",10000))`, you are already calling `sock_listen` and passing the result of this call into the `Thread` constructor.

You need to pass the callable `sock_listen` as `target` and the arguments for `sock_listen` separately to `Thread`:

`receiver = threading.Thread(target=sock_listen, args=("localhost",10000))`

Your target function will then be called in the new thread after you started it.

Comment: Oh yeah that works… I could feel that it was something like that going on, thanks a lot  !